# Plotting several lines with different alphas in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw several lines from a numpy matrix form with the same color, but different alphas. I tried to specify it via rgba_colors since this works for scatter plots. However, that is on a point basis, while here I would like to have it per line. I have tried

```
num_lines = 4
lines = np.outer(np.arange(1,num_lines+1), np.arange(1,10))    
alphas = np.linspace(0.1, 1, num_lines)
rgba_colors = np.zeros((num_lines, 4))
# for red the first column needs to be one
rgba_colors[:, 0] = 1.0
# the fourth column needs to be your alphas
rgba_colors[:, 3] = alphas
plt.plot(lines, color=rgba_colors)
```

However, that leads to:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LineCollection`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

num_lines = 4
y = np.outer(np.arange(1,num_lines+1), np.arange(1,10))  
x = np.tile(np.arange(y.shape[1]), y.shape[0]).reshape(y.shape)

segs = np.stack((x, y), axis=2)

alphas = np.linspace(0.1, 1, num_lines)
rgba_colors = np.zeros((num_lines, 4))
# for red the first column needs to be one
rgba_colors[:, 0] = 1.0
# the fourth column needs to be your alphas
rgba_colors[:, 3] = alphas

lc = LineCollection(segs, colors=rgba_colors)
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While the matplotlib `scatter` function accepts both a single color or a list of colors as an argument, the `plot` function only accepts a single one. You still can use a simple loop to obtain what you need:

```
num_lines = 4
lines = np.outer(np.arange(1,num_lines+1), np.arange(1,10))    
alphas = np.linspace(0.1, 1, num_lines)

rgba_colors[:, 3] = alphas
for line, alpha in zip(lines, alphas):
    plt.plot(line, color='red', alpha=alpha)
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to avoid loops, but this does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html
you may specify only one color for one `plot()` command.